# My loop duplicates the last char... (Language C)(feof)(char by char)

Tags: feof

Yo guys,

I'm trying to read a text file:

```
while(!feof(fp)){ 

    fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);

    printf("%c", c);

}
```

But... the output always duplicate the last char, I dont know why... :/

Any idea?

Comment: Are you saying that the output of your program is the first character of the input file `fp` repeated?  Is it [the first char] repeated once for every character in the input file? Is this really the entirety of your loop and I/O? What does your input file look like? Is `c` an `int` or an `unsigned char`?

Comment: c is a char... I'm reading a text file that looks like it "+1 2", but the number 2 appear duplicated when I use that code, dont know why. Anyway, the last char is always duplicated...

Comment: possible duplicate of ["while( !feof( file ) )" is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I've wondered that too, finally I found an [answer](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1046476070&id=1043284351)!

I could not explain it any better, so check out the link